# I created navbar.js file, I defined it in app.js ,But i got this error. How solve i this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ERROR in ./src/App.js 13:37-43
export 'default' (imported as 'Navbar') was not found in './components/Navbar' (module has no
exports)

Comment: Open Navbar.js and add this line at the end `export default Navbar;` (and please google error messages before posting here)

Answer (score 0):

you have not exported your Navbar component from Navbar.js file. please ask the question with more information, provide code for each file.

if you have exported using default

```
export default Navbar
```

you will import like this

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar.js"
```

if you have exported without default

```
import {Navbar} from "./Navbar.js"
```

for this you export like "export const Navbar" or in case of class "export class Navbar"